# Update vba, macros and user forms in older workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, module

Good day,

My Google-fu has failed me as I've searched and am unable to locate the information I require.

I have a master workbook, when it is ran, it will create another workbook based on cell values and the master closes and remains unchanged, the new workbook is then used to store information and is saved to an Archive folder when the workbook is closed.  This archived workbook can be opened in future to edit or resend data but if the master workbook is opened it starts all over as blank and as stated creates a new workbook again.

It has 5 modules, 14 userforms and also uses code in ThisWorkBook and some save codes on different worksheets throughout.

When I update something, like add or modify a userform, I email the change out to 13 different emails and attach the master workbook which they download and replace it and carry on.  The workbook has to remain as one file and has to run without internet access as they're MS Surfaces that are used in an outside work environment and internet access is not always available.

I have found some things regarding this but they usually only export and import bas.

I would like to know if anyone knows of a way or a source to update all the modules and userforms in workbooks in Archive.
The user will download the master from the email, replace the previous and when it is ran it will pull the updated forms and code from it and export them to the older workbooks in the Archive folder so the new additions can be used in the older workbooks.  I also require that the information on the worksheets in the old workbooks remains unchanged.
The master would need to update multiple workbooks at first run, then not run again until the next update when it replaced again.  I can do this by using a cell value like if A1 = 1 then don't run for example.

I haven't tried anything yet as I only found the bas export, importer as stated.

I apologize for my wall of text and I hope I am clear on my scope.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't you ever change the structure/layout of the worksheets? Seems like that would need to stay in sync with the code/forms.

Comment: See also: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx  which has everything you need to do this

Comment: Thank you, I will check this page out.